# Sharepoint List - Creating a new view - Column Doesnt exist

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I get this error when creating a new view - employeeLoginID was an older column I previously deleted or renamed. any workarounds?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Re-create the column again.  Be sure to name it the exact same name: ***EmployeeLoginID***.  I am presuming that the internal name of the column was also *EmployeeLoginID*.

If you get an error when you try to create the new *EmployeeLoginID* column try to empty the site’s recycle bin as well as the site collections recycle bin and second stage recycle bin.

**Sub-Site recycle bin is located at:**

https://**Your-Tenant**.sharepoint.com/sites/**Site-Name-Slug**/**Sub-Site-Slug**/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=5

**Site Collection First-Stage recycle bin is located:**

https://**Your-Tenant**.sharepoint.com/sites/**Site-Name-Slug**/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=5

**Site Collection Second-Stage recycle bin is located:**

https://**Your-Tenant**.sharepoint.com/sites/**Site-Name-Slug**/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=13